# WCF Security exception when calling from Windows Service

Tags: wcf, windows-services

I have some code which consumes a WCF service. The service is protected by basic authentication, so on creating the client, I'm using the following code:

```
    BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    httpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
    httpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
    httpBinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
    httpBinding.Security.Transport.Realm = service_realm;

    EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(service_address);

    Service.ServiceClient client = new Service.ServiceClient(httpBinding, address);

    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = service_username;
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = service_password;
```

Works fine when I run the code from a console app. But when I run the same code from a windows service, a MessageSecurityException is being thrown telling me that my request was unauthorized. For some reason it seems to be using the current Windows account for authentication, because my own account does have access to the service. But I don't want it to, I want it to use the stored credentials. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

WCF **basicHttpBinding** does not support *plaintext* credentials; the reason is because the moment you want pass credentials around on a transport binding, WCF requires the underlying transport to be a *secure* transport, such as SSL.

In order for your code to work, you would then need to use service via `https` or using certificates or encryption.

Comment: That could be so, but this used to work when I had a normal app.config. What changed is that I now create the binding programmatically and that's what seemed to have caused the problem. I think your statement is true for a wsHttpBinding, but not basicHttpBinding.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be fixed using this config:

_httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

_httpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
  _httpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
  _httpBinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;

_httpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
  _httpBinding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default;

_httpBinding.AllowCookies = false;
  _httpBinding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
  _httpBinding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
  _httpBinding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
  _httpBinding.TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
  _httpBinding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
  _httpBinding.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
  Service.ServiceClient client = new Service.ServiceClient(_httpBinding, _address);

client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = service_username;
  client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = service_password;